# Anyone here good with Html? I'm trying to access a website without visiting it

Tags: html

So, my school blacklisted discord and i am trying to reach it without actually visiting it, i have the HTML code for it but it doesn't work after that, does anyone know how to do this?

I have already tried a few different HTML environments, such as scratchpad and codepen.
I must also mention that i am on a chromebook and most of the features relating to dev tools are in fact disabled, chrome extensions, task manager, developer mode, crosh, etc

Comment: Sorry if im an idiot by how this all sounds but yeah.....i dont mean to waste anyones time.

Comment: How 'bout you don't try to work around your school's explicit restrictions? I know it's fun, but really…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with HTML, you have to be able to talk to the webserver to get a response (which your school has blocked). Try using a [VPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network) or a [web-based proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server).

Comment: ;-; alright, thank you.

Comment: @TimothyJohnson Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this frustration when I was back in school and college. Lucky enough for me we had Windows 10 machines and could do a lot more than a Chrome book.

However, you still have a few options that might work for you.

1: As you are using a Chromebook the first thing I would try is using a Chrome extension such as Ultra Surf.

2: Chromebooks also allow you to install Android apps so you could look for a VPN that is on the app store I believe Turbo VPN is a free one.

3: Chromebooks also allow you to manually configure VPN in the settings, this one is a little more tricky but should get the job done. Check out this link for guidance on how to do this https://www.androidauthority.com/reviews/.